# Mysql code to trigger update on column from different table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update, inner-join

I am using a database that has 2 tables for city and country. City table has ID(PK), population and country code. Country table has Code(PK) and population.
If an update happens to city population, the country population should be updated automatically.The issue is how to implement this in a proper update statement.
It should follow the general pattern below:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER diff_pop
  AFTER UPDATE 
  ON city
  FOR EACH ROW 
  ...
  UPDATE country SET NEW.population=country.population-city_old+city_new 
WHERE country.population=new.population;
```

I think there could be many ways to solve this, so any input is appreciated.

Comment: Store aggregated data, and even more update it, whereas it can be calculated - this is bad idea in most cases.

Comment: *I am not sure if it absolutely needs a Join or multi-table query for the update* That's true - both OLD and NEW are NOT tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER diff_pop
AFTER UPDATE 
ON city
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE country 
SET population = population - OLD.population + NEW.population 
WHERE country.code = NEW.countrycode;
```

If it is possible that the city may be moved from one counntry to another then

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER diff_pop
AFTER UPDATE 
ON city
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE country 
    SET population = population - OLD.population 
    WHERE country.code = OLD.countrycode;
    UPDATE country 
    SET population = population + NEW.population 
    WHERE country.code = NEW.countrycode;
END
```

PS. Do not forget to create AFTER INSERT and AFTER DELETE triggers...

---

> That does not work, it is ambiguous syntax according to mysql, since there is no distinction between population column on city and country. – seneca

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74ff5148110e3c1fbf4d452e5ac1a1bb). Try to refute it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the logic, that is way I was confused.

Comment: @seneca If you need in additional explanations - ask, specify what must be explained more detailed.

Comment: Thank you for understanding, it got messed up the the code I already had, that is why it gave me an error. Still my question is who does Mysql know which row to update in the country table? Where is the connection between the City and Country tables?

Comment: @seneca *Where is the connection between the City and Country tables?* `WHERE country.code = NEW.countrycode;` condition sets this connection. `country.code` (may use simple `code` - because `country` is the only table used in the query) is a column in the table `country`, and `NEW.countrycode` is a value of `countrycode` column in current row (one row!) processed by the trigger (i.e. in `city` table). Remember, that `OLD` and `NEW` are NOT tables. Think about `NEW.countrycode` and similar like they are single variables with special names.